# Why do value showed in tensorboard is not consistent with actual value?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I visualize mean square error for test set along with the training in tensorboard, but the curve showed in tensorboard is not consistent with the value I logged.

The logged values are here, it converged to 80~100.

[image]

The curve in tensorboard is here, it converged to less 50:

[image]

So why? I am sure my code is right, the same problem was appear on my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you run the operations at a same time.

sess.run([train_op, summary_op])

not like

sess.run(train_op)
sess.run(summary_op)

Comment: Thanks.My code actually run at different time, like ```sess.run([train_op, mse])```, ```sess.run(summary)``` following, but the second ```run``` don't update parameters I think, so why it may lead to different value?